# Защита cookies от атак мошенников

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, cookie

Какие существуют атаки с использованием кукис, и как их предотвратить? Имеется в виду работа с кукис моего домена.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот тут немного написано:

[How can ASP.NET or ASP.NET MVC be protected from related domain cookie attacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9636857/how-can-asp-net-or-asp-net-mvc-be-protected-from-related-domain-cookie-attacks)